# Can this describe a shape other than a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: quadrilateral *n*]

Let quadrilateral *n* have vertices A, B, C, and D. If side AB is congruent to side CD, and angles ABC and CDA are also congruent. Can you show this is not necessarily a parallelogram?

It does not follow the conditions for a parallelogram, yet my math teacher and I were unable to show a counter example or prove that it is or is not.

One cannot dissect it and use triangle congruence, for it leads to ASS.

Can someone show it is not a parallelogram, or even better, show a counter example?

Comment: Are you secretly assuming it is a convex quadrilateral? Because a nonconvex one is an obvious counterexample.

Comment: rschwieb - there was a visual in the given situation that implied it was convex

Comment: typically in geometry problems visuals are taken with a grain of salt as to what they imply.

Comment: rschwieb I would like to see your concave counter example if you could make an image.

Comment: You're right about the visual, too, but this was a first year geometry test very early in the year(very cryptic imagery that could still be accurate wasn't really present)

Comment: Isn't it obvious what a nonconvex example would be? Something like ⋈.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be a non-parallelogram.

[image]

Regarding the triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDA$ - due to the two solutions for the inverse sine, $\measuredangle DAC$ and $\measuredangle ACB$ can be different.

Note that if the given $\measuredangle ABC = \measuredangle CDA$ is *obtuse*, there is only one viable solution for the inverse sine and the shape is indeed a parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. I haven't done much work with sine and cosine yet, but now I can see how the 2 triangles viable with ASS can interact.